Huge gap at the bottom of the webiste
Here is my website: https://enmasantos.github.io/vitality_vista, for a personal project I am making, on below the footer there is a huge white space. And I have checked margin both for the footer and surrounding elements.
Here is the code I am using for the footer:
/* footer.css */

.footer {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 1.5rem 0;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease; /* Smooth transition for dynamic color change */
    height: 16%;
    border: 15px solid red;
}

.social-icons a img {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease, fill 0.3s ease; /* Smooth color and scale transition */
}

.social-icons a img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.footer-bottom p {
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    margin: 0;
    color: #f1f1f1;
}


here are my general style, but don't know if they have any relationship with what's going on:
/* global.css */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/* Root Variables for Color Palette and Fonts */
:root {
  --fandango: #a4036f;
  --bittersweet: #ff595e;
  --sunglow: #ffca3a;
  --yellow-green: #8ac926;
  --steel-blue: #1982c4;
  --text-color: #333;
  --background-color: #f9f9f9;
  --font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  --font-size-base: 16px;
}

/* General Reset */
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}

body {
  font-family: var(--font-family);
  font-size: var(--font-size-base);
  color: var(--text-color);
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  line-height: 1.6;
}

/* Headings */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  color: var(--fandango);
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

/* Paragraphs */
p {
  
  color: var(--text-color);
}

/* Links */
a {
  color: var(--steel-blue);
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Buttons */
button {
  font-family: var(--font-family);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
}

/* Container Layout */
.container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Utility Classes */
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.mt-2 {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.mb-2 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

/* Dashboard Container */
.dashboard-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(15rem, 1fr)); /* Responsive card size */
  gap: 1.25rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}

/* Card Styles */
.dashboard-card {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 0.625rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}

.dashboard-card:hover {
  transform: translateY(-0.3125rem);
}

.dashboard-card h3 {
  color: var(--fandango);
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.625rem;
}

.dashboard-card p {
  color: #333;
  margin-bottom: 0.625rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.dashboard-card button {
  padding: 0.625rem 1.25rem; /* Spacing is now based on rem */
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0.3125rem;
  background-color: var(--bittersweet);
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1rem;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.dashboard-card button:hover {
  background-color: var(--sunglow);
}

body, main {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}


Well, you don't have enough content to fill the screen. The simplest solution is to put the background color of the footer on the body instead, and then make the main background color white. Or you can go for sticky footers etc, but that starts to get hacky and hard to control across devices.

Do you want the footer at the bottom of the viewport, at the bottom of the content, or a mixture (at minimum at the bottom of the viewport but if the content is taller than that then at the bottom of the content)?

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Layout_cookbook/Sticky_footers (Sticky footers)

You need to set the following classes
html,body {height:100%;} and main {height:100%;}

You have very less content due to which height of body is remaining short and due that there is huge gap at bottom.
If you are going to add more content inside dashboard-container then you might not need to do anything additionally. If not going to add more content then you need to add this two properties min-height: 87vh; and align-items: start; to dashboard-container.

You can move your adjust the CSS in footer class like following style
.footer {
   color: #ffffff;
    padding: 1.5rem 0;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease; 
    height: 16%;
    border: 15px solid red;
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0;
}


Won't this mean the footer overwrites some content under certain circumstances?

yeah using position: absolute with bottom : 0 on the footer may be it to overlap with content above.

Once you have the body set to 100% and the main set to 100% you can try using a negative margin to bring it in, I know it sounds  like a cheap trick and honestly I am not the best developer as I am rather new, but I had a bootstrap project that for some reason had the same issue and using a negative margin was the only thing that worked for me.
